# ERROR 1288: The target table is not updatable in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am trying to run a small trigger with following query in Mysql :

```
create trigger sample_trigger after delete on my_network
  for each row
  begin
      update (select active from my_network_ref where id=old.rid limit 1) vnetr set vnetr.active=0;
  end;
```

After running these trigger in MySQL Workbench , i ma getting following error

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1288: The target table vnetr of the UPDATE is not updatable
SQL Statement:
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mam_db`.`sample_trigger ` AFTER DELETE ON `my_network` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 update (select active from my_network_ref where id=old.rid limit 1) vnetr set vnetr.active=0;
END
```

Any syntax error or structural problems ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you cannot update a subquery.  Instead:

```
update my_network_ref
    set active = 0
where id = old.rid
limit 1;
```

Normally, you would use `order by` when using `limit`.

Comment: How can i use order by ? can you suggest some example with this query ?